# How to numerically approximate a function?

Tags: macroeconomics, numerical-methods

what are some numerical analysis techniques that I can use to approximate functions? For example, say I've got the demand equation

$$q = a p^b + c p^d$$

and I want to find the price that clears the market for a given $q$.

Solving it numerically for a given set of parameters and $q$ is easy, but what if I want the function that inputs $(a,b,c,d,q)$ and outputs the equilibrium $p$? There's no closed-form solution, so are there any numerical techniques for approximating functions?

Comment: Hi @solowsupremacy. I'm not sure how that would work since P is on both the LHS and RHS. Also, do you know of any methods other than Taylor approximation? That was just an example - the problem I'm facing is more complicated. Thanks!

Comment: I missed the double $p$'s. Have you tried using the [Newton-Raphson method](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408n/CurrentWeb/LM4-8-2.php)? While you can do that manually, [here](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/newton-raphson-method)'s an implementation in R, accompanied with examples and a description of the process, if you're interested. Your goal is to find $p$ such that $f(p) = ap^b + cp^d - q = 0$ for given values of $(a,b,c,d,q)$.

Comment: If what you have is a demand function you will in addition need a demand function to determine the two unknowns q and p in equilibrium.

Comment: A quick numerical method might be to use binary search.